# Is mysql field_count changed in php or I am wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

As far as I can remember, if return set is empty. mysqli_result::$field_count is always 0.

However, I find mysqli_result::$field_count is always the columns number in select statement after I upgrade php to 5.4.4-14_deb7u4 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 14:37:41) in Debian Linux.

```
<?php
//always return field_count = 2, although 'niuniu' is not in the table;
$sql = "select _id, _id from user_info where name='niuniu'";
```

Am I seeing the pink elephants?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're after the number of *fields*, not the number of *rows*?

Have a look at [mysqli_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Comment: Now I am using num_rows instead. However, I just remember field_count works too. As my code worked before.